# Create IBInspectable of unicode character

Tags: ios, unicode, swift2, icons, ibinspectable

I've created some Icon Fonts using websites like (**http://fontastic.me/**) which gives you .ttf file.

you can use it by

```
myLable.text = "\u{e002}" //
print("\u{e002}")     //
print("\u{1F496}")   //
```

this works nicely but I want to pass string directly using storyboard.

Then I start working with UILabel Subclass and create @IBInsectable for unicode string. but this was not working. following is code of IBInspectable.

```
@IBInspectable internal var myString: String? {
        didSet {
            text = "\u{e002}"       //          this works
            text = "\\u{\(myString)}" //\u{e002}    this not
        }
```

or

```
let myString = "e002"
print("\\u{\(myString)}")   //\u{e002}
```

even this also not working

```
print(myString)
text = String(UTF8String: myString!)
```

but this will print only text it's suppose to print Icon like `print("\u{e002}")` this.
how to solve this, what I'm missing ?

thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You need to use NSScanner class that helps you to convert NSString to unicode**

On **IBInspectable** just pass only code without **\u** use NSScanner class to convert NSString to Unicode and you can use as unicode character

Like if you want to use **\ue002** then only set **e002** to NSSString

Below is example what you want, like subclass of UILabel and have property with IBInspectable element.

```
class LabelSubClass: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable internal var myString: String? {
        didSet {
            let scanner: NSScanner = NSScanner(string: myString!)
            var code: UInt32 = 0
            scanner.scanHexInt(&code)
            let unicodeString: String = String(format:"%C", UInt16(code))
            print("unicodeString: \(unicodeString)")

            text = unicodeString
        }
    }
}
```

[See here how to set unicode to inspectable element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoeWb.png)
[Here you can see output of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jEzR.png)

Comment: Happy to help, happy coding.